# Why am I seeing an error about _OBJC_CLASS_$_CPGraphHostingView with Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I downloaded the Core Plot example application, but when I compile it I saw a few errors.  I then added the Core Plot SDK, but in this SDK there is no class named CPGraphHostingView.  Therefore, I added the class manually from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/iPhoneOnly/CPGraphHostingView.h?r=627908b81b0bb23c8814e19ea6be70d208665c75).

However, I now see the following error:

```
ERROR -  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPGraphHostingView", referenced from:
```

How can I work around this to get the sample application to compile?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the [step-by-step instructions](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) on the Core Plot wiki and you should be fine.

Note that the SDK install is considered experimental at this time, and I know that others have reported issues with using it, so I'd recommend following the instructions for using the static library instead.

Comment: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

 This type of error i got after some changes in my settings please help me ...

Comment: @user616281 - That's not an error, that's a result of an error.  What does it say in the build log before this?